# After upgrading Android Studio to 4.1, code is not fully colorful

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.1

After I upgraded Android Studio to 4.1 code colors is like below and mostly the code text is black. I want to get all code colorful , btw I tried invalidate caches/restart and rebuild however issue still exist.

[image]

Comment: Well, go to your preferences and set your preferred colours.

Comment: the old colors were good and i cant remember them , is there a way to restore them without setting them manually

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot with full IDE window? Do you face the same issue with new projects?

Comment: solved , check first answer

Answer (score 1):

finally problem solved , issue was from some outdated IDE plugins , after I uninstalled them everything worked fine .

Comment: it was Android ButterKnife Zelezny plugin for me, I have just disabled it then everything is working correctly!

Comment: The same for me

Answer (score 0):

Install the flutter plugin on android studio

preferences > plugins

Comment: I am not using flutter

Comment: or any plugin required by android development

Comment: i uninstalled ButterKnife plugin and issue was solved